# Excel: Formula Returning from conditional

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to return formula of other cell (column L) if choose item in column A.
Example:
if answer, then return =I5 & " " & J5
if foo, then return '=I7 & " " & J7 & " " & K7 & " x " & L7

I want to return the formula instead of the result.
[image]

Comment: This is confusing to me. Where do you want the result to appear - what is the input value?

Comment: The input value is column A, B, C and D. Output is column E from formula of L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this function in a public module

```
Function GetFormula(rng As Range) As Variant
    GetFormula = rng.Formula
End Function
```

I think this is what you want. There are several options for how you want that formula returned such as R1C1 style.

**Edit**

Oh I think I get what you want more. Ok to apply the formula you have in your blue table to whatever cell you want in column F you can call the `Indirect` function.

So for example if you want to apply the formula `'=I7 & " " & J7 & " " & K7 & " x " & L7` to your column F then call `=INDIRECT(I7 & " " & J7 & " " & K7 & " x " & L7)`. In your column `I` don't include the `=` sign. it will make it a bit easier.

You can use Vlookup to find where this should be applied by using your lookup item in column A in your reference table (the blue table). Return the formula in column `I`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by nesting your formulas.

put this in E5

```
=IF(A5 = "answer", A5 & " " & B5 & " " & D5, 
 IF(A5 = "bar", A5 & " " & B5 & " " & C5, 
 IF(A5 = "foo", A5 & " " & B5,
 "No If Formula Here yet")))
```

I started the formula off with the first two formatting's for you.

Comment: Gimp my example is short, but reality my options is more of 40 diferents itens... and ai?

Comment: It looks like some of your fomrulas are the same, so i'd recommend grouping them so you can use lines like: ` IF(OR(A5 = "stick,A5 = "send", A5="cat"), A5 & " " & B5 & " " & C5,"nothing") ` 

The reality is that if you need to handle 40 different wats to check and combine columns, you need to write that code somewhere. The above is a Formula based approach due to the original request. However, i'd suggest that for readability, you could make a UDF in VBA. This approach is more complex, but would be easier to update and comment (document).